# CSS3 Columns - Widows / Orphans

Tags: css

I've looking around to see if there have been any decent way of handling widows and orphans in CSS3 multi-columns, but have been disappointed to find none. I've tried the `widow` and `orphan` properties themselves, but they didn't do anything.

Does anybody know of a way to use CSS3 multi-columns and handle widows and orphans?

Comment: To check current browser support: https://caniuse.com/css-widows-orphans .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An interim solution to this is to add

```
display: inline-block
```

to the block level element you wish to avoid breaking across columns. I recently needed this for `<li>` and `<dl>`. Works well for either.

Comment: The problem with this is that the bullet points align to the bottom of the inline-block. Did you have a workaround for that?

Comment: @wu-lee to remove bullet points just add "list-style: none;" to the ul tag.  This solution worked great for non list items as well like divs. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The spec says the [algorhitms should honor widows and orphans](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#filling-columns). Not sure how many do. But you can control some of it yourself by saying *never break inside a `p`*.

For that, you basically use

- `break-before`
- `break-after`
- `break-inside`

They take values like `auto` which is default, and `avoid` and `always`. Plus a few extra.

Opera supports it, and you can find info here: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/css/multicolumnlayout/

Comment: It appears that you can only either force new columns or let it do it automatically.. There doesn't appear to be a setting to limit widows/orphans to two lines or something like that

Comment: Test page to check how browser supports `orphans` and `widows` for columns: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/widows.html
Chrome supports it, IE10 also, Firefox 24 doesn't.

Comment: And Firefox probably won't support it for a while, given the bug history... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137367

Comment: Somewhat related to that, mstensho at Opera is currently fixing multicol code of Blink (and WebKit!) to make it as awesome as Presto.